# Bootstrap 3 modal doesnt always activate ajax code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this I just don't seem to be able to resolve it.

I am using the bootstrap modal to return ajax content from specified url. (using $.removeData() between loads to remove content).

The problem comes with running JS on content from the form presented in the modal.

I am currently using (simplified) from within the final file (returned by ajax):

```
$('#myModalLg').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).on('submit', 'form', function(ev) {
        ... event handler for form...
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** along with other event handlers (datepicker for within modal included) but this code is only loaded once and then fails to activate again until the full page is reloaded

On close code:

```
$('#myModal, #myModalLg').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(e.target).removeData();
    $(e.target).off('shown.bs.modal');
    $('#myModal, #myModalLg').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find(':input:first')[0].focus();
    });
});
```

I would be expecting the handlers to run each time #myModalLg is shown and then when it is closed it removed what has been entered and restores each time but doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: Have you consider to delegate it (if this event bubbles), e.g: `$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal, #myModalLg', function(e) {...});` ?

Comment: the hidden.bs.modal code runs everytime, its only the shown.bs.modal code which doesn't "refresh" on second load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never turn off your shown.bs.modal have you looked into the [One](http://api.jquery.com/one/) Event In JQuery:

I'm not sure if this will help but it seems like your redeclaring your shown.bs.modal multiple times you might want to change that to a one instead of on

```
$('#myModal, #myModalLg').one('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find(':input:first')[0].focus();
});
```

Comment: this seems to have fixed it, there must have been some kind of duplication happening as shown.bs.modal was turned off on hiding but this seemed to resolve anyway!

Comment: Sweet, Glad it all worked for you! I was just about to follow up let me know if there's anymore issues